# Scala/java reflection - `newInstance` throws InstantiationException

Tags: java, scala, reflection

```
object classof extends App {

 trait Config {
    def test(): Unit
  }

  case class Test() extends Config {
    override def test(): Unit = println("test")
  }

  val s = classOf[Test]

  s.newInstance().test()

}
```

The above code works fine, but when you run it as a scala worksheet, it throws `InstantiationException`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
reflection.A$A20$A$A20$Test.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
```

I am facing this issue primarily when executing tests. For example

`Animal.config.newInstance().test` where Animal is an instantiated object and config holds `val config: Class[_ <: Config] = classOf[Test]`.

I don't have sound knowledge on java reflections. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Just a question. Do all the classes you are trying to instantiate have constructor with no parameters? If not, this could be it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error

Comment: @Vlasec Well, no i am just instantiating a simple config class with no parameters. Funny part is, it works on my main code. Its failing in tests and worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

I run your example first in IntelliJ idea with a ScalaWorkSheet, and I felt into your same error, my conclusion is that reflection is not well implemented in scala sheet, for me the log is:

(I tried different ways expecting different results):

```
trait Config {
  def test(): Unit
}

case class Test() extends Config {
  override def test(): Unit = println("test")
}

Test.getClass.getSimpleName

val t: Test = classOf[Test].getConstructors()(0).newInstance().asInstanceOf[Test]

t.test()

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(TestingSO.sc)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(TestingSO.sc:58)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(TestingSO.sc:41)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(TestingSO.sc:419)
...
```

The most rare thing is:

```
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(TestingSO.sc)
```

That's the name of my scala

Then I made a simple scala class:

```
class Testing {
}

trait Config {
  def test(): Unit
}

case class Test() extends Config {
  override def test(): Unit = println("test")
}

object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val s = classOf[Test]

    s.newInstance().test()
  }
}
```

And works just fine...

**Conclusion**

Careful with Scala Sheet, some times may be a sh*t haha

Answer (score 0):

Note the `A$A20$A$A20$Test` name. It hints that this is really an inner class (worksheets have to wrap code into a class/object because Scala doesn't support top-level code directly; you'll see the same in the REPL).

And inner classes require an instance of the outer class to construct. So there is no constructor without parameters and simply calling `newInstance()` can't work.